# Using spread syntax while wrapping functions recursively in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, styled-components

I was trying to convert my `styled-component` mixin module to typescript but encountered a problem that I can't solve (in the `chain` method). Live playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVwDZIsATgU02GBeGACgEp8A%20GAAwCgY6YB3ASwBMoALALhgEYAGPgDcGAblr12mJgHN2UbvyHsxNUJFgQAjggCGWFviIQmAL0zdo6JmGmk8FGvUasO3ACQBvY2YC%20Yp5Iycu5epph%201DTU1lCY6HA6wJgwALZMAB7WAJJgsfGJyR7idIgoaFg43FAAngAOmCBw8MioGNhgxTBauvpVdQ1N3XqYLNQ%201NQ19TDA7DrWIwCyGdm5cQlJhkVOANoACjDWMADWmNWNqStgOXkbmAC63IQAdK960hDce3o6KZh5EAAPGlMtc1vkkvt7mQ7BQSOQulArDYxhM1NBLqDPpjVrcCjAAGQwDwzObWJ6w0nzMBLK43db4nxbTqlVoVMAAGk6Q30XKcAHp%20TBXs9OrNqdxEGBgFAmOAiKRtk56OjYOKFiwAPIAIwAVpgZV89LKdEhAeqaSxlqD6RDMBQCB5xsr6Eh-jBEsAEClkDpYiwAEr-BDoXAEADk4c6TlVJzOEEMOv1Muep2qEEIIOsEGIzzgTCQeUIaYRJYAhHgIxbw6QdAni2cLlmwXiksQdvcYNH6GmIHmQOgAKKJdgN6oIpUumPgDHNgBiCGlsvlBGbEB2afu3ZdFpGSYNUA3Z07BClMrluBeb3QHyN6F%20-ziQKmAxxYAXS4vMOJ26ndE93q%20v6QZQCGuAANSrlcH7nuAV7PO8Oa-n%20sZYKBoYwcuYYKgiAE%20kgfojCBYHIVOaFgTA%204pnWxjSGAhDkRhi6wZyMAcEwSF-k4zpTj4xC-oxuC7lqeoHh6CbCdauIMkknTjOMQA).

```
// Sample mixin methods
const fullscreen = () => `
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
`
const squared = (size: string) => `
    width: ${size};
    height: ${size};
`

interface mixinInterface {
    fullscreen: typeof fullscreen
    squared: typeof squared
}

type chainedMixinInterface = {
    [P in keyof mixinInterface]: (...args: Parameters<mixinInterface[P]>) => () => string
}

const mixins: mixinInterface & { chain: () => chainedMixinInterface } = {
    fullscreen,
    squared,
    // ...other mixin methods
    chain: function () {
        const chainedObject: Partial<chainedMixinInterface> = {}
        let accumulatedReturn = ''
        // get mixin keys without 'chain'
        const keys = Object.keys(mixins).filter(key => key !== 'chain') as (keyof mixinInterface)[] 
        keys.forEach(key => {
            const mixinFunction = mixins[key]
            // wraps subsequent mixin methods
            chainedObject[key] = function (...args: Parameters<typeof mixinFunction>) {
                accumulatedReturn += mixinFunction(...args) // Error: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
                const returnAllChainedValues = () => accumulatedReturn
                return Object.assign(returnAllChainedValues, this) // pass along the methods to be chained
            }
        })
        return chainedObject as chainedMixinInterface
    }
}
```

This is the use case for chain:

```
const Div = styled.div`
    // returns a function that returns the chained results
    // which will be called by styled-component's tag function
    ${mixins
        .chain()
        .fullscreen()
        .squared('50px')
        // ...other mixin methods
    }
`
```

By calling the `chain` function, it wraps subsequent calls to mixin methods. Instead of returning a string, it returns a function that returns the accumulated result (string) from all of the chained methods.

#### Problem:

Even though I specified `...args` as the parameters of the `mixinFunction` that is currenting being iterated on, it isn't a tuple, but a union of tuples. Therefore, TypeScript throws an error in the following line, where I spread the `args` in the `mixinFunction` call.
I haven't found a way to solve this problem. Is there a way to sidestep this issue by only modifying the typing, without changing the underlying JavaScript?

Comment: For the record, `...` is not an operator. It is a syntactic element, but not part of the expression grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not do type narrowing on a case basis, it only narrows to general types. Consider the following code

```js
interface MyType {
    n: number,
    s: string
}

function selfAssign(a: MyType, key: keyof MyType) {
    a[key] = a[key]; // Error: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'
}

selfAssign({ n: 3, s: 'abc'}, 'n');
```

Even though `a[key] = a[key]` is clearly typesafe, TS doesn't have a type that represents "type of `a[key]` whatever it is".

For all TS knows, you're trying to assign a value that might either be a number or a string, to a property that either only accepts numbers or only accepts strings.

It says the lefthand `a[key]` is of type `never` because no value can satisfy both `number` and `string`. In a slightly different case the error would be different but the princip is the same.

In your case, `mixinFunction` can be one of a few functions with a different signature each, so the type of `...args: Parameters<typeof mixinFunction>` is the intersection of all those possibilities rather than a particular tuple, and therefore it's not possible to call `mixinFunction` with `...args` as the parameters.

If you don't want to change the underlying JS code in a way that'll allow TS to recognize the type match, you can relax the type safety by performing a cast. One such option that seems to work is

```js
accumulatedReturn += (mixinFunction as unknown as (...args: any) => () => string)(...args)
```

The above code casts `mixinFunction` to `(...args: any) => () => string` which allows calling it with any parameters, but it's  still relatively safe because it only affects that specific line where you immediately call the function with the actual `...args`.

The intermediate cast to `unknown` is apparently also needed because otherwise TS complains about the cast not being reasnoable.